# adding a new cell to a table using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a button which is named reject and when it is clicked it is supposed to show a form with a text and another button.

Everything is working fine except it only add a cell to the first row only, no matter where the reject button is or whether it in the second or third row  it will show the new cell after the first row.

i want the small form to be added in the same row where the reject button was clicked.

this my code:

```
<table asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Pending" class="table table-bordered table-sm table-striped" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Check Time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="demo">
        @if (Model == null)
        {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7" class="text-center">No Model Data</td>
            </tr>
        }
        else
        {

            @foreach (var p in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@p.Id</td>
                    <td>@p.Email</td>

                    @if (@p.CheckOut == null)
                    {
                        <td>Offline</td>
                        <td>@p.CheckIn</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>Online</td>
                        <td>@p.CheckOut</td>
                    }
                <td>

                    <button name="button" value="accept" asp-action="Accept" asp-route-id="@p.Id" class="btn btn-success">Accept Request</button>
                    <button id="re" class="btn btn-danger" data-id="@p.Id" onclick="fun()">Reject Request</button>
                </td>
                    <td style="display:none;" id="comment">
                            <form >
                                <input type="text" name="newcomment" id="newcomment" />
                                <button name="button" value="reject" asp-action="Reject" asp-route-id="id" class="btn btn-primary">Comment</button>
                            </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function fun() {
        document.getElementById("comment").style.display = 'block';
    }
```

Comment: IDs must be unique within an HTML document. You are creating duplicates with the code that you are outputting inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JQuery to show the td area .

Firstly , modify this line :

```
<button id="re" class="btn btn-danger" data-id="@p.Id" onclick="fun()">Reject Request</button>
```

To

```
<button id="re" class="btn btn-danger" data-id="@p.Id" onclick="fun(this)">Reject Request</button>
```

And modify your js function to find the next `td` of current button :

```
function fun(elem) {
    $(elem).closest('td').next('td').show();
}
```